# How to Sort HashMap <String ,Object> using Object Value

Tags: java, sorting, spring-mvc, comparator

I'm having trouble applying sorting mechanism through my application.

Reason was sometimes sort are not accurate and also the comparator thing in java still not clear for me, but i have used sort here and there.

Now, current problem is as follows.

I have

```
HashMap<String, ModelX.ContactModel> unsortedModelContacts = 
new HashMap<String,ModelX.ContactModel>(contacts.size());
```

After that I fached

`contactlist` and using `for` loop I have put the values as follows:

```
unsortedModelContacts.put(stringvalue, modelContact); 
//object having name , and other details
```

How can I sort the `unsortedModelContacts` sorting `modelContact.getName` property?

Comment: `HashMap`s aren't sorted maps. So you can't. Use a `SortedMap` implementation.

Comment: Are you trying to sort based on Map values rather than keys?

Comment: hey guys that why i have asked its not clear for me to do that...i used the hashmap for just collection purpose...

Comment: What is this `stringvalue` you are using as key in the `put` method?

Comment: it like a phone number 65354878 but no gruntee to sort using that value ..instead the contact name

Answer (score 1):

```
SortedMap<String,ModelX.ContactModel> sortedModelContacts = new TreeMap<>();

for( ModelX.ContactModel modelContact: contactlist ){ // same list as before
     sortedModelContacts.put( modelContact.getName(), modelContact);
}
```

You can now access entries of this map in sort order of the name property.

Note: this assumes that names are unique. If this isn't true, you'll have to use a multimap or

```
Map<String,ModelX.Set<ContactModel>>
```

and modify the put and other accesses accordingly.

Comment: Thankyou Sir , unknown class SortedMap and no import has been shown i use 1.6 java

Comment: `java.util.SortedMap` is an interface. Its been there since JDK 1.2. One implementation of this map is `java.util.TreeMap`.

Answer (score 1):

If your map's key is different from the name field then you can consider using this approach. Writing a separate comparator

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import sample.ModelX.ContactModel;


public class SortMapSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, ModelX.ContactModel> unsortedModelContacts = new HashMap<String,ModelX.ContactModel>(10);

        unsortedModelContacts.put("1", new ModelX.ContactModel("James"));
        unsortedModelContacts.put("2", new ModelX.ContactModel("Mary"));
        unsortedModelContacts.put("3", new ModelX.ContactModel("John"));
        unsortedModelContacts.put("4", new ModelX.ContactModel("Amanda"));
        unsortedModelContacts.put("5", new ModelX.ContactModel("Charles"));

        System.out.println(sortMap(unsortedModelContacts));
    }

    private static Map<String, ModelX.ContactModel> sortMap(
            Map<String, ModelX.ContactModel> unsortedMap) {

        List<Entry<String, ModelX.ContactModel>> list = new LinkedList<Entry<String, ModelX.ContactModel>>(
                unsortedMap.entrySet());

        Collections.sort(list,
                new Comparator<Entry<String, ModelX.ContactModel>>() {

                    @Override
                    public int compare(Entry<String, ContactModel> o1,
                            Entry<String, ContactModel> o2) {
                        return o1.getValue().getName().compareTo(o2.getValue().getName());
                    }
                });

        Map<String, ModelX.ContactModel> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, ModelX.ContactModel>();
        for(Entry<String, ModelX.ContactModel> item : list){
            sortedMap.put(item.getKey(), item.getValue());
        }
        return sortedMap;
    }

}
```

Comment: i apprecaited it... i will be testing the result and let u know Sir